# Problema ao tentar abri minha aplicação java

Tags: java

Estou tentando gerar um .jar de um jogo mas na hora de executar a aplicação, ela não abre e quando tendo abrir pelo cmd da erro. alguém[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] pode me ajudar. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Essa mensagem parece ser coisa relacionado à versão do java.

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde, tudo bem?

O problema é a versão do java o qual o programa foi compilado, e a versão do java onde está rodando o .jar

Por Exemplo, as vezes na sua IDE, está rodando o java 11, mas na maquina a o java 8.

Veja qual a versão está na IDE, e pelo terminal, rodando java -version no terminal você consegue ver qual a versão da maquina.